# How To load Images from Drawable to SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-drawable, simplecursoradapter

I Create a List view with **Simple Cursor Adapter** in that adapter i fetch my Sqlite Column names now i want to add images to the same adapter from Drawable Folder How can we Do that Give ideas and Sugession thanks..

Here is My Code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           final int[] imageResource =new int[] {R.drawable.juice, R.drawable.medicinebowl, R.drawable.kam};
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
     dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(this);
            try {
                dbHelper.openDataBase();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            cursor = dbHelper.gettitles(sqLiteDatabase);
            String[] from = new String[]{dbHelper.TITLE, String.valueOf(circle)};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.title,R.id.circle};
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.title_row, cursor, from, to);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: have your problem solved or not yet

Comment: I create a object to hold images from `Drwable int[] imageResource = {R.drawable.juice, R.drawable.medicinebowl, R.drawable.kam};` and i attach that in my adapter like `String[] from = new String[]{dbHelper.TITLE, String.valueOf(imageResource)};` @Tony

Comment: you need an array for objects ids

Comment: can u explain in detail plz @Tony

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: @vasanth you need to bind your view please look at my answer

Comment: TYPE_ONE what it refers?? @ArsalImam

Comment: Its basically the purpose of your image

Answer (score 0):

You can simply doing this by adding this line

```
your_imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.drwable_image);
```

if you have not created you custom adapter which extend SimpleCursorAdapter you can do this

```
  String[] columns = new String[] { People.NAME, People.NUMBER };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_entry, R.id.number_entry };

SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_example_entry, cursor, columns, to);
```

the colomns array should contain the date and the to array should contain the ids of object you want assign data to them

and this for images

```
    listAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){

   public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
       if(view.getId() == R.id.your_image_view_id){
          int imageType = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            int imageToBeShown=0;
            switch (imageType) {
            case TYPE_ONE:
                imageToBeShown=imgs[0];
                break;
            case TYPE_TWO:
                imageToBeShown=imgs[1];
                break;
            case TYPE_THREE:
                imageToBeShown=imgs[2];
                break;
            case TYPE_FOUR:
                imageToBeShown=imgs[3];
                break;
            case TYPE_FIVE:
                imageToBeShown=imgs[4];
                break;
            case TYPE_SIX:
                imageToBeShown=imgs[5];
                break;
            }
            ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(imageToBeShown);

           return true; //true because the data was bound to the view
       }
       return false;
   }
});
```

setting the image resource should be depend on your row type

Comment: how to attach in Adapter? can u say in detail please? @Tony

Comment: you can use this and to be honest @Arsal mentioned this at first

Comment: ((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(imageresource);?? @Tony

Comment: setImageDrawable (android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) in ImageView canot be applied to (int[]) this is What it shows when i try to apply`((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(imageresource);` @Tony

Comment: check my updated answer use set image resource instead

Comment: Check My Updated Code @Tony

Comment: use setImageResource instead of setImageDrawable @vasanth

Comment: SetImageResource (int) in ImageView Cannot be Applied to (int[]) @Tony

Comment: becuase you can't set an array of images try it to one image like this R.drawable.juice

Comment: ` int[] imageResource ={R.drawable.juice};adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                if (view.getId() == R.id.circle) {
                    //...
                   // ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(imageResource);
                   ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(imageResource);
                    return true; //true because the data was bound to the view
                }
                return false;
            }
        });` Still the SAme Problem @Tony

Comment: you need to make an extra condition for the type of the row in order to set the appropriate image id you can't set all the array at the same type i just give you an example of how u can achieve this

Comment: `((ImageView)view).setImageResource(imageResource[R.drawable.juice]) `when i try this my App was Crash and it say column **'[I@41cbb158' does not exist** @Tony

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '[I@41cbdd90' does not exist
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
            at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:317)
            at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:66)
            at com.example.aeiltech.sidd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
            at`

Comment: i canot find the Updated Answer

Comment: i need to know on what colomn in ur data base you depend to set the appropriate drawable?

Comment: I my Custom Activity i created a Simple Textview and ImageView and i fetch the database and display in that textview

Comment: here in order to help i have take a snippet from @arsal could and if it helps you should give him the Credit

Comment: I want to set image of Title Column from my database @Tony

Comment: so your switch case will be on the title for example

Comment: if the title is orange u can set R.drwable.orange as image resource

Comment: ` switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.image:
                int imageType = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                int imageToBeShown=0;
                switch (imageType) {
                case ??:
                    imageToBeShown=imgs[0];
                    break;`

Comment: in the above code what can i want to place insist of ?? @Tony

Comment: The value from the appropriate column in ur data base

Comment: Using cursor = dbHelper.gettitles(sqLiteDatabase); i get titles from my database so what i want to use in Switch case @Tony

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you need your own custom layout and also overiding `setViewBinder` method, Below is an example which can help you to understand,

YourClass.java

```
// The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] { DBHelper.KEY_IMAGE_TYPE, DBHelper.KEY_HOUSE,
            DBHelper.KEY_PRICE };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] {  
            R.id.icon,
            R.id.bowler_txt};

    SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.listrow, cursor, columns, to, 0);
    dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor,
                int columnIndex) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.image:
                int imageType = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                int imageToBeShown=0;
                switch (imageType) {
                case TYPE_ONE:
                    imageToBeShown=imgs[0];
                    break;
                case TYPE_TWO:
                    imageToBeShown=imgs[1];
                    break;
                case TYPE_THREE:
                    imageToBeShown=imgs[2];
                    break;
                case TYPE_FOUR:
                    imageToBeShown=imgs[3];
                    break;
                case TYPE_FIVE:
                    imageToBeShown=imgs[4];
                    break;
                case TYPE_SIX:
                    imageToBeShown=imgs[5];
                    break;
                }
                ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(imageToBeShown);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

listrow.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bowler_txt"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bowler"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In the above code, `imgs` is the integer array variable for your image drawable's ids...! Good Luck

Comment: TYPE_ONE what it  refers?? @Arsal Imam

Comment: The type field if you have multiple images could be set in the list view row

Comment: How to use Row case Depend on My Title @ArsalImam

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this method

```
int[] imageResource = {R.drawable.image_1, R.drawable.image_2, R.drawable.image_3};
```

and pass this to your SimpleCursorAdapter constructor.

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter doesn't contain ImageView itself...!

Comment: Then why you need drawables inside the adapter ?

Comment: I create a object to hold images from `Drwable int[] imageResource = {R.drawable.juice, R.drawable.medicinebowl, R.drawable.kam};` and i attach that in my adapter like `String[] from = new String[]{dbHelper.TITLE, String.valueOf(imageResource)};`@beardedbeast